# Could S300 expert connect with a laptop via a RS422/USB converter?

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This's my first time using ROS ,sorry if the question is trivial

---

Could S300 expert connect with a laptop via a RS422/USB converter?

And I have to ask more question about library for use to make Navigation

Can the sicks300 package or cob_sick_s300 be ues for the **s300 expert** sensor?

---

I'm planning to use it for the Navigation stack

Thank you very much

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328805/could-s300-expert-connect-with-a-laptop-via-a-rs422/usb-converter?/) by [thitapa.sae](https://answers.ros.org/users/44081/thitapa.sae/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-07-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, you can connect this via a RS422/UWB converter.
I can't speak for the sicks300 package, but the `cob_sick_s300` supports the expert, even though not all possible configurations. The `sicks300` package seems to be obsolete though.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2019-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1